# Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js ->

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I updated my react-native from **0.61.3** to **0.62.3** and did the necessary changes.
My IOS is running fine. But My Android, when i run `npx react-native run-android` it builds the apk in my simulator, but in my terminal i get this outcome:

```
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.000]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.200]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/Interstitial.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.150]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/RewardedVideo.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.160]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/SyncTree.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.170]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.180]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.180]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/Query.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/QuerySnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentChange.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.190]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.200]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/FieldValue.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.210]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/functions/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.220]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/task.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.230]  LOG      o payload no reducer undefined
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.230]  LOG      o payload no reducer undefined
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.250]  LOG      o payload no reducer undefined
[Wed Aug 17 2022 14:57:38.270]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/lib/create-icon-set.js -> node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/lib/ensure-native-module-available.js -> node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/lib/create-icon-set.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

I thought i could ignore the warnings, but my android simulator get this image:

[image]

My package.json

```
    "moment": "2.29.3",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.259.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "6.0.0",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think the error displayed in your simulator is related to require cycles warning.

Comment: @sushrut619 i am going to see my code better, i will post any change, thanks!!!